# Creating new entities in `postFlush` doctrine event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm struggling to find a way to perform a `persist()` and `flush()` methods after the final flush (I mainly want to do it in `postFlush` event).

I collect the necessary entities in `onFLush` event (with changeSets) and wait up until all entities (which I collected) got flushed to get their id's (auto incremented). 
So that I have at this point an array with all needed entities and their change sets and their id's set.
Then I want to create new entities (let's call them "traces") based on fields of previously collected entities and persist & flush "traces" in database.

But I'm really stuck here as I can't know entities id's in `onFlush` event, and I can't persist & flush them in `postFlush` when they already have their id's set.

Currently Doctrine documentation states following:

> postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush(). EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.

And if I dare do this, it ends up in a recursion and php fails with an error.

Which approach may I take here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do a check if you aren't flushing "traces" entity and then perform your "traces" creation. That shouldn't loop.

Also you might want to look at symfony's [eventDispatcher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) . You could dispatch your events manually, since it might be cleaner.

More details on "traces" would be helpful, from what I can imagine it is some kind of a changelog, history; so for that I might suggest [EntityAuditBundle](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAuditBundle). It works pretty good with doctrine and is not hard to set up, I am using it myself.